# How to write a function that checks if a variable is defined and is a number?

Tags: php

In the past when I needed to check if a variable was set **and also** a number, I would do:

```
if( isset($_GET['var']) && is_numeric($_GET['var']) )
```

But I think that's kind of ugly, especially when I need to check a bunch of variables in the same if statement, so I made a function:

```
function setAndNum($var)
{
    if(isset($var) && is_numeric($var))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I pass an undefined variable to the function, like this (supposing the variable in the GET array is undefined):

```
if( setAndNum($_GET['var']) )
```

I get the php error:

> Notice: Undefined index: ...

So the whole purpose of the function is basically defeated (or half the purpose, at least ;) ).

One thing that confuses me is how the isset() function works, and why I can pass an undefined variable to it but not to my own function?

Is it possible to make my setAndNum() function work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is with `$_GET` being an array. When you pass `$_GET['var']` to your function, this array value is already looked up and used as an argument to the function. Therefore you cannot effectively check the presence of `'var'` in `$_GET` from *within* this function. You could rewrite it a bit to make it work for array values, something like this:

```
function setAndNum($key, $array)
{
    if(array_key_exists($key, $array) && is_numeric($array[$key]))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
if( setAndNum('var', $_GET) )
```

Answer (score 3):

It's good practice to verify a key exists before using it:

```
if (array_key_exists($_GET, 'var')) {
  // do stuff with $_GET['var']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function setAndNum(&$var)
{
    if(isset($var) && is_numeric($var))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: correct answer, but it would have been better to explain it than simply provide the code.

Comment: the problem here is that by nature of using a reference, you *create* the variable if it doesn't exist in the calling scope. the return value of the function is still correct and logical, but calling the function causes side effects.

Comment: @chris - can you expound on the "side affects" you mentioned? I tried using a reference, and it seems to work great.

Comment: Sure. `print_r($_GET);setAndNum($_GET['idontexist']);print_r($_GET);` notice that the array entry is created. The reason is that php references point to a variable, and, you cannot point to nowhere, so php creates the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try using this version:

```
function setAndNum(&$var)
{
    if(isset($var) && is_numeric($var))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@` operator to prevent error reporting:

```
setAndNum(@$_GET['var']);
```

This way, the error message of the non-existant index will not be printed, and the return value will be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write two functions, one that checks for an array and one that checks for normal variable

```
function setAndNum($var)
{
    if(isset($var) && is_numeric($var))
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
}

function setAndNumArray($array, $key)
{
    if(isset($array) && isset($array[$key]) && is_numeric($array[$key]))
       return 1;
    else
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if you are using variables from GET or POST method you may do like this as these are super globals.

```
function setAndNum()
{
    if(isset($_GET['var']) && is_numeric($_GET['var']))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

now coming to your another query. isset checks whether a variable is s et or not like

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// any code under button click
}
```